# Typescript not reading null when returning

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I have a problem with Typescript not reading my return type correctly.
I am defining a function with a return type of `something | null`. And what typescript does is to read only the `something` type ignoring the null, which can be returned, when I call the function.

```
function nullornot(): null | string { // here is says it returns null | string
    return null
}

const response = nullornot() // but here is says it returns string
```

[image: Function declaring]

[image: Function call]

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
   "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
   "compilerOptions": {
     "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types"],
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
     "lib": ["ESNext"],
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "noUnusedLocals": true,
     "noUnusedParameters": true,
     "removeComments": true,
     "sourceMap": true,
     "target": "ESNext",
     "outDir": "lib"
   },
   "files": ["src/@types/graphql.d.ts"],
   "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules/**/*",
     ".serverless/**/*",
     ".webpack/**/*",
     "_warmup/**/*",
     ".vscode/**/*"
   ]
}
```

My webpack.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.json', '.ts'],
    symlinks: false,
    cacheWithContext: false,
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: './tsconfig.paths.json',
      }),
    ],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  optimization: {
    concatenateModules: false,
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      {
        test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [
          [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.serverless'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
          ],
        ],
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          experimentalWatchApi: true,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.graphql?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'webpack-graphql-loader',
            options: {
              // validate: true,
              // schema: "./src/schema.graphql",
              // removeUnusedFragments: true
              // etc. See "Loader Options" below
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To type the result as `string | null`, you need to enable `strictNullChecks` in `compilerOptions` like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "strictNullChecks": true
}
```

See the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you don't have the `strictNullChecks` flag set to true in the tsconfig. Therefore TS won't enforce null checks, so for all intents and purposes it's just a string.

See how in [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&ts=4.1.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGEAbVcBOY5QBQCUAXMmqogD6IDOUmMYA5ogN6ID07iAFgKaa9EMajQCGATxEwoiAVBDYRKdJRp0GjAFCIds3vOyl0mgL6bNEBLT3UADlcEBeIxmy5CHLgCMQMvgKERagkpGTkFMCD1Jk0gA) where strict null checks are off it behaves the same as you're seeing, but once you [turn it on](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGEAbVcBOY5QBQCUAXMmqogD6IDOUmMYA5ogN6ID07iAFgKaa9EMajQCGATxEwoiAVBDYRKdJRp0GjAFCIds3vOyl0mgL6bNEBLT3UADlcEBeIxmy5CHLgCMQMvgKERagkpGTkFMCD1Jk0gA) the type of `response` is `string | null`

If this is a new project I'd recommend activating the strictest settings for the best type safety.

Comment: Thanks it works! I will follow your suggestion by enabling these options `strictNullChecks, noImplicitAny, noImplicitThis, alwaysStrict `